# why my vite app deployed in githubpage not working

Tags: reactjs, github, vite, github-pages, github-pages-deploy-action

i have created my portfolio using vite+react and it works well on localhost . i have saved entire code in my github repo and when i deploy this using github pages it shows "Unexpected Application Error!
404 Not Found" .
link to my github repository : https://github.com/AkshayNS28/MyPortfolio

tried deploying vite app using github pages.
app not working after deploying showing Unexpected Application Error!
404 Not Found error message on screen

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.